# How to format a list of strings into an html table?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, list

I'm trying to send a sample message in gmail. My message contains text which is a list of items. I wanted to print each list item in a tabular format. Right now I am trying with the new line but every time when the string length is different, it is not aligned properly with the email. Can someone let me know how to achieve keeping my list items inside a message?

Following is the demo code I am trying with.

```
def html_table(list_name):
  print('<table>')
  for sublist in list_name:
    print('  <tr><td>')
    print(sublist)
    print('  </td></tr>')
  print('</table>')

l = ["--> ServiceName is ec2 , this is a sample string inside list item1    ",
     "-------- ServiceName is s3 , this message is a sample string inside list item2------"]
message = """
    Hi ,
    The following are different aws services  
    {0}
    Best regards,
    Team
    """.format('\n\t'.join(map(str, l)))

print(message)
```

Comment: Have you considered a module such as [PrettyTable](https://pypi.org/project/prettytable/)?

Comment: I'm not aware of it, let me check it. thanks for info

Comment: Also check if your email program uses a fixed width font - most wont so different letters have differen widths and you wont be able to simply "space out" text with spaces. You might be able to add a html table into your mail.